# Stop a button from receiving touchEvents and detect "touch in" in Android

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I have several Buttons in my screen. All of them with same View.OnTouchListener.

What I am seing is that when I tab one of them I get ACTION_DOWN, then if I move I get ACTION_MOVE even if I am moving outside the button area. If I touch out and then move inside I get nothing.

What I want is a way to say "stop sending events out of this area" or "stop sending events" (and I detect if event is inside the area or not)

This is my OnTouchListener:

```
OnTouchListener touchListenerPad=new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                Log.d("PadControl", "event= "+event.getAction());
                if(v==up)
                {
                    Log.d("PadControl", "btn= up");

                    return false;
                }

                if(v==down)
                {
                    Log.d("PadControl", "btn= down");

                    return false;
                }

                if(v==right)
                {
                    Log.d("PadControl", "btn= right");

                    return false;
                }

                if(v==left)
                {
                    Log.d("PadControl", "btn= left");

                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

        up.setOnTouchListener(touchListenerPad);
        down.setOnTouchListener(touchListenerPad);
        right.setOnTouchListener(touchListenerPad);
        left.setOnTouchListener(touchListenerPad);
```

Comment: why don't you use onClick instead of onTouch?

Comment: Because onClick(View v) only triggers when I tab down and then up.

Comment: so you want to create a function that detect the touch is inside or outside the button?

Comment: No, that´s the easy part. I want to know how, having that function, I can ask Android not to send more events until I tab down or go inside another button.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, what I've though is first you must detect the location of your button with [View.getLocationOnScreen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) or [getLocationInWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int%5B%5D%29) after you get the x and y of your button you can save the region of the button from the x until x + button width and from y until y + button height and after that you can restrict the event if the event is outside the region your buttons with getting x and y of the touch event with [MotionEvent.getRawX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX%28%29) and [MotionEvent.getRawY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawY%28%29). I hope this answer can help you but if you have another question regarding my answer feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just ignoring the event when it is outside wont have the desired behaviour; because I would still have an event on this button, and what I want is not to receive any event until other button is excited.